# Burley push button wheels and axle?

Tags: wheels, trailer, diy

I'm looking into building my own trailer and I want something similar to Burley's push button wheel system.

My question is, where do I obtain similar wheels/axles?

Here is the Travoy, one of their trailers that uses such a wheel:
[https://www.amazon.com/Burley-Design-Travoy-Commuter-Trailer/dp/B0038LPO5Y](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0038LPO5Y)

[image: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71GT9v5zagL._SL1442_.jpg]

Replacement ones sold by Burley are pricey, anyone else have any luck looking for a similar product?
https://www.bikeparts.com/BPC417920/burley-replacement-wheel-16%22-alloy-push-button-axle

[image: https://www.bikeparts.com/images3/xlarge/WE3402.jpg]

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic.

Comment: On the other hand, compatibility questions aren't considered off topic and this is basically about fitting third party replacement wheel to Burley.

Comment: @ojs I'm not seeing that. The two questions are "Where do I obtain [Burley push-button] wheels/axles?" and "anyone else have any luck looking for a similar product?" Nothing about fitting -- just what product to use and where to buy it?

Comment: My mistake. Still I'm not sure that this needs to be closed. As far as I understand, the product rec ban is to avoid endless comparisons between brands, not to prevent looking for a commercially available solution to a problem.

Comment: "wheelchair" wheels and axles are often similar in their mountings.  Differences is indoor wheelchairs can be solid tyres not pneumatic.

Answer (score 2):

If what you really want is Burley hub/attachment guts, just ask around for someone getting rid of a Burley trailer with rotted out or missing fabric. They've sold a lot of trailers and many of them sadly get put outside to languish before eventually getting thrown away once they get nasty.

Alternatively, Ali Express has a lot of the approximate kind of stuff you're looking for. I don't know if you know the term "stub axle," but that is broadly what you're talking about, an wheel axle like a car or a wheelchair where the support is only on side.

Comment: Relevant posting  http://bikeretrogrouch.blogspot.com/2018/10/a-trailer-project.html

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to see in the Burley photos, but the replacement photo shows a conventional wheelchair stub axle.

These are not particularly rare, but they're not bicycle parts.  Instead, you'll need to look into medical or assisted living equipment providers.

Another option is to make contact with the equipment department at your local hospital.

Here's a closer photo of the wheelchair axles from my trailer.

[image: Own work]
 two wheels, one showing inside and one showing outside.

[image: Own work]
Main axle housing, showing retainer clip.

As you can see, the main axle is a pipe/tube with a retainer clip.  This engages a slot milled into the wheel's stub axle.

The axle itself is a piece of round bar stock with some grooves machined into it.  There's a circlip holding the cartridge bearings into the wheelhub on the inside, and probably a simple bolt head on the outside.

In short, any competent machinist / lathe operator / fitter and turner could make these.

Mine do not have a press-button on the outside to release the wheel. It is just a solid cap.